# How to read a ;-separated CSV in Java that can countain an unknown number of elements

Tags: java, csv

I know there exist a lot questions about reading CSV files, but I simply can't find one that fits my needs.

I try to get keywords from a keywords.csv that can be in a form like this. The delimeter is always the ";".

```
SAP;BI; Business Intelligence;
ERP;
SOA;
SomethingElse;
```

I already looked into openCSV and so on, but I can't find a functioning example how to do that (simple) task.

I tried this:

```
public void getKeywords()
    {
           try {
               int rowCount = 0;
               CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), ';');
               String[] row = null;
               while((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {

                   System.out.println(row[rowCount]);
                   rowCount++;
               }
               //...
               reader.close();
           }
     catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File Read Error");
    }
```

But it will just return the first element. I don't know what I do wrong. Im new to coding as you may have noticed :)

EDIT: Got what I wanted, thanks for your help!

```
 while((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                   for (int i=0; i<  row.length; i++ )
                   {
                       System.out.println(row[i]);
                   }
```

Please help an old man out.
Thank you!

Comment: Read a line, split at the `;` characters, process the results.

Comment: Im new to coding, can you give me an example how this could work? Thank you

Comment: It works by reading the Java doc for String, and observing that String has a `split` method.

Comment: I added the code I tried to the post.

Comment: Note that CSVReader is simply combining the readline and split operations into one -- not a lot of functionality for having to import another package.  You'd be just as well off doing it yourself.

Comment: @HotLicks, I know this question is old and dead, but take a look at [this article](http://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/). Saying CSVreader is only combining readlines and splits is pretty far off base, it's not incredibly complex, but it starts getting messy quick if you try to parse it yourself. [Check out the source](http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/) and you'll see it's definitely a non-trivial problem.

Comment: @Adam - But it's unnecessarily confusing to the newbie, and doing it "by hand" is quite educational and helps make tools like CSVReader more intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using openCSV, you could use this code:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), ';');
```

That will open the .csv file, read it in, and use a `;` as the delimiter. A similar example can be found on the openCSV home page.

Once you have the file read in, you can use the data with something like the following:

```
String [] nextLine;
// Read from the csv sequentially until all the lines have been read.
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

Where `nextLine` is a line from the file, and `nextLine[0]` will be the first element of the line, `nextLine[1]` will be the second, etc.

**Edit:**

In your comment below, you mentioned that you don't know how many elements will be in each row. You can handle that by using `nextLine.length` and figuring out how many elements are in that row.

For example, change the above code to something like:

```
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    if(nextLine.length == 1) {
        // Do something with the first element, nextLine[0]
        System.out.println(nextLine[0]);
    }
    else if(nextLine.length == 2) {
        // Do something with both nextLine[0] and nextLine[1]
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + ", " + nextLine[1]);
    }
    // Continue depending on how you want to handle the different rows.
}
```

Comment: that's about what I did (see edit in my Post.) I have the problem, that i can't iterate the array elements there, since I don't know how many keywords there will be in my file.

Comment: I updated my answer, but the problem is, if the rows are different lengths, how do you know what data you want to use? What are you trying to use this data for, and how do you know what is or is not important for what you are doing?

Comment: The user types in keywords (for searches) in this csv. I extract these keywords in my workflow and want to pass them in an array /another form. So the example I gave is a user worst case input. Just the ";" is right, but it can be ina new line, with spaces, without. That's the base from which I have to operate unfortunatelly. Thank for your great help so far

Comment: I got what I wanted (see post above) thank you! Damn it still has blanks in it though!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file using the readLine() method from the Scanner class. The output of this method is one line of the input file. You can then use the String.split(";") method to get the individual elements. You can then move to the next line using the methods in the Scanner class and then continue from thereon.
You will get a number of arrays - one corresponding to each line from the input file. You can just combine them to get what you want.